# Pandas dataset into an array for modelling in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Can we run scikit-learn models on Pandas DataFrames or do we need to convert DataFrames into NumPy arrays?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame` with `sklearn`, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

data = [(0.2, 10),
        (0.3, 12),
        (0.24, 14),
        (0.8, 30),
        (0.9, 32),
        (0.85, 33.3),
        (0.91, 31),
        (0.1, 15),
        (-0.23, 45)]

p_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=3, n_init=10)
kmeans.fit(p_df)
```

Result:

```
>>> kmeans.labels_
array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: It would be more informative to show how to deal with a DataFrame with named columns, since this is what causes more problems. A combination of this an the other answer would be great.

Answer (score 6):

Pandas DataFrames are very good at acting like Numpy arrays when they need to. If in doubt, you can always use the `values` attribute to get a Numpy representation (`df.values` will give you a Numpy array of the values in DataFrame `df`.